# Objective C: Issue in calculating height of individual labels

Tags: objective-c, ios, size, height, uilabel

I have a label added to a cell which has a dynamic height based on the text to be added to it. I have set my font size to be 12 as seen below:

```
CGFloat height = [CustomCell getIndividualLabelHeight:text];
NSLog(@"height of commet:%@ is %f",commentText, height);

CustomOHAttributLabel *label = [[CustomOHAttributLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN, 2*CELL_SPACING+totalCommentLabelHeight, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN*2), height)];
[label setLabelwithText:text fontSize:12 andSubString:userName withURL:url];
```

However, in my getIndividualLabelHeight method, if I set the font to 12.0 as well (in setting of CGSize size), the text in the label might be truncated. It is only when I set it to 14 will the text not be truncated.

```
+ (CGFloat)getIndividualLabelHeight:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    //The full text will only show when I set fontsize to 14 (instead of 12)
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return size.height;
}
```

Anyone has any idea why I cannot set the same font size in my get height method as the actual font size I am using for my text?

I have added my implementation code for the CustomOHAttributLabel for further reference

```
 @implementation CustomOHAttributLabel

 - (CustomOHAttributLabel*) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) 
     {

     }
     return self;
 }


 - (void) setLabelwithText:(NSString *)text fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize andSubString:(NSString *)subString withURL:(NSString *)url
 {
     NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:text];
     [attrStr setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
     [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

     [attrStr setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize] range:[text rangeOfString:subString]];
     [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:[text rangeOfString:subString]];

self.attributedText = attrStr;

[self addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:url] inRange:[text rangeOfString:subString]];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code:-

```
CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel *commentsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];;
    commentsTextLabel.tag =50;
    [commentsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *text=@"cakghaahsdlajsldjasdsa;dkas;dkasdkasdasp'dlasp'dlas'dlas'dlas'dlas'dlas'dlasdlasdlasdlasdlas'das'dlasdas";
    [commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"size:14]];
    labelsize=[text sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(268, 2000.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    commentsTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 24, 268, labelsize.height);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:commentsTextLabel];
    [commentsTextLabel release];
```

from this code you label height will adjust dynamically.
Make sure if you are adding this label in your table view cell so don't forgot to make the cell height dynamic also.

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you have any idea why my current method does not work properly (if I set the font size in the getheight method and the label font size to be the the same?)