# UILabel align top right

Tags: objective-c, alignment, uilabel

I want to align the text from an UILabel to the top right,

This seems to me the most logical answer, but it is not working. 
It aligns to Top-Left instead of Top-Right

```
[ValueText setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentRight];
[ValueText sizeToFit];
```

NOTE: I can also work this out with the following:
ValueText x position = 320 - ValueText width

Comment: I think you will get what you want if you remove second line.

Comment: Well, then CGRect frame = ValueText.frame; frame.origin.x = 320 - frame.size.width;ValueText.frame = frame;

Comment: No, then it just aligns to the right and not at the top.

Comment: you can calculate height of text and then calculate y.

Comment: calculate height of label you can like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577894/objective-c-issue-in-calculating-height-of-individual-labels

Comment: Thanks, your second opinion worked fine for me!
(My first response was on your first opinion, that didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

As @stosha replied:

Well, then CGRect frame = ValueText.frame; frame.origin.x = 320 - frame.size.width;ValueText.frame = frame;

This worked for me.